# increasing of performance in split access database

Tags: ms-access

I have a split database in access 2003 with back-end and front-end. BE contains my tables and FE contains forms ,macros and etc.My database is very slow.Have you any idea to make my  DB performance better ?

Comment: Is the BE stored on a network or on the local machine?  Also ensure that you have your table indexes set correctly, especially on Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: BE stored on network and tables are indexed.

Comment: Have you see these? http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm  AND http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/improve-performance-of-an-access-database-HP005187453.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about the above issues I don't have any idea but the second one you can put the back-end on network and the front-end on your machine, then if you any user enter a record it automatically add in to the back-end.

yeah, it is ok to put it indexed.

By network, it means local one not internet.

Comment: This seems to only suggest what the OP already confirmed they have done.